# Inputing info from a structure to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

Been trying to figure out how to input information into an array and output it from structured variables. I can input and output the information easy without using arrays, however I am trying have a list of workers inputed from the keyboard. I also need to calculate the wage earned for each worker, but If I can just figure out the format of the simple information from the first three variables I can figure that part out on my own. I have tried to call the input function in the array but have had no success so I just deleted it and left the functions.

```
 #include<iostream>


using namespace std;

struct Worker

{

    int idNumber;
    int hoursWorked;
    double hourlyRate;
    double earned;

};

void input(Worker & theData);
//Postcondition: theData.idNumber, theData.hoursWorked, and theData.hourlyRate are given input values
// the user must input into these values.
void print(const Worker &);

void input(Worker[], int howMany);

void  print(const Worker[], int);



void main()
{
    Worker arr[10];
    Worker Data;
    input(Data);
    print(Data);

    input(arr[10],7);

    system("pause");

}

void input(Worker& theData) {
    cout << "Enter the Employee idNumber ";
    cin >> theData.idNumber;
    cout << "Enter the Hours Worked. ";
    cin >> theData.hoursWorked;
    cout << "Enter the HoutlyRate for under 41 hours. ";
    cin >> theData.hourlyRate;
}

void input(Worker arr[], int howMany)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        input(arr[i]);
    }
}

void print(const Worker& w) {
    cout << w.idNumber << "\n" << w.hoursWorked << "\n" << w.hourlyRate << "\n" << w.earned << endl;
}

void print(const Worker arr[], int howMany)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        print(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to store the input information in an array of structs?

Comment: I have to write four functions to make an array of worker structures.
1.      one to input an array of Worker structures

2.      one to figure the earned for each Worker

structure in the array

3.      one to output the array of Worker structures

4.      one to count the number of workers who have worked overtime.  Return the answer through the function call

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please consider to ask a question and post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. This sounds like coursework, so I'm not going to suggest using a std::vector. Look up std::vector, by the way, and use it when you can. It'll save you a lot of grief.

To use an array, you first need to know the size of the array and reserve space. There are a number of ways to get the number of workers, but this is probably the simplest:

```
int main()
{
    int howMany;
    cout << "How many?";
    cin >> howMany;

    Worker * workers = new Worker[howMany];
```

After that, it's pretty much keep doing what you're doing, but call the array-based functions and clean up when you're done.

```
    input(workers, howMany);
    calc(workers, howMany);
    print(workers, howMany);
    system("pause");
    delete[] workers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I am understanding you correctly, you would like to be able to read in information about a bunch of workers and store it into an array of structs. Correct my if I am wrong, but if that is what you would like to do I think you can actually cheat this a little bit using the single worker `input` function like so.

```
struct Worker
{
    int idNumber;
    int hoursWorked;
    double hourlyRate;
    double earned;
};

void input(Worker& theData) {
    cout << "Enter the Employee idNumber ";
    cin >> theData.idNumber;
    cout << "Enter the Hours Worked. ";
    cin >> theData.hoursWorked;
    cout << "Enter the HoutlyRate for under 41 hours. ";
    cin >> theData.hourlyRate;
}

void input(Worker arr[], int howMany)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        input(arr[i]);
    }
}

void print(const Worker& w) {
    cout << w.idNumber << "\n" << w.hoursWorked << "\n" << w.hourlyRate << "\n" << w.earned << endl;
}

void print(const Worker arr[], int howMany)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        print(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Some notes, you want to delete the const from the array input function. You are going to modify the array it can't be const. I added some spaces after the "Enter the blah. " so that it looks prettier. You can figure out the calc on your own as you said, just follow the form here to figure out how to do that for an array of things. Once you have written to the function for a single guy, it is pretty simple to do it for the array as you can see.

Also for your education just remember that arrays are inherently pass by reference so that's why we can just throw them into the pass by reference functions with no problems.

I should add that in the future you can access the parts of each workers information from the array directly by using:

```
arr[i].idNumber;
arr[i].any_struct_variable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I did not realize I had that constant on that input function. The functions should definately serve my purpose, however, and i feel dumb for asking this, but I can not figure out how to call the function in the main driver program. I am going to edit my program with the calls that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping! I finally figured it out and It is working well.

```
    #include<iostream>


using namespace std;

struct Worker

{

    int idNumber;
    int hoursWorked;
    double hourlyRate;
    double earned;

};

void input(Worker & theData);
//Postcondition: theData.idNumber, theData.hoursWorked, and theData.hourlyRate are given input values
// the user must input into these values.
void print(const Worker &);

void calcInput(Worker[], int howMany);

void input(Worker[], int howMany);
void  print(const Worker[], int);
void calc(Worker & theWage);



void main()
{
    Worker Data;
    int howMany;

    cout << "How many?";
    cin >> howMany;

    Worker * workers = new Worker[howMany];
    input(workers, howMany);
    calcInput(workers, howMany);
    print(workers, howMany);

    system("pause");
    delete[] workers;

}

void input(Worker& theData) {
    cout << "Enter the Employee idNumber ";
    cin >> theData.idNumber;
    cout << "Enter the Hours Worked. ";
    cin >> theData.hoursWorked;
    cout << "Enter the HoutlyRate for under 41 hours. ";
    cin >> theData.hourlyRate;
}

void input(Worker arr[], int howMany)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        input(arr[i]);
    }
}

void print(const Worker& w) {
    cout << w.idNumber << "\n" << w.hoursWorked << "\n" << w.hourlyRate << "\n" << w.earned << endl;
}

void print(const Worker arr[], int howMany)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        print(arr[i]);
    }
}

void calc(Worker & theWage)
{
    if (theWage.hoursWorked <= 40)
    {
        theWage.earned = theWage.hoursWorked * theWage.hourlyRate;
    }
    else
    {
        int basePay;
        basePay = theWage.hoursWorked * theWage.hourlyRate;
        theWage.earned = (theWage.hoursWorked - 40) * 1.5 + basePay;
    }
}

void calcInput(Worker arr[], int howMany)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        calc(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite what answer is intended for. Regardless, you still need the `void calc(Worker arr[], int howMany)` function and probably should call calc after the input function. You can also eliminate the need to have and maintain the forward declaration ghetto by putting `main()` at the bottom of the file and placing all of the other functions above their first use.